# Multi Table Use in SQL?

Tags: sql

Example: 
I have a table called 'Friends', in 'friends' they each have their own ID called ID. 
I have a table called 'Parents', in 'parents' they each have their own ID as well, uses same ID key as the one in 'friends'. 
In 'Friends' there is a column called ParentID which is equal to the ID of the parent from the 'parent' table. (e.g if ParentID is 5 in friend table, in parent table it would be 5 as ID for their parent).

Friend table: 
ID
Parent ID 
First Name 
Last Name

Parent Table: 
ID 
ParentID
First Name 
Last Name

(the ParentID in 'Friend' is connected to the ID in 'Parent')

My question is, on friend table I want to select the ParentID but I want it to show the first and last name of the parent instead of the ID number, how do I go about this?

Comment: You use a join.

Comment: You can Google `JOIN`.

Comment: @Eric -- most people would prefer to join google.

Answer (score 0):

use join-

```
SELECT p.FirstName,p.LastName
FROM Parent p
JOIN Friends f
ON p.ParentID=f.ParentID;
```

Comment: What about friends that don't have parents?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple join

```
SELECT F.First, F.Last, P.First as P_First, P.Last as P_Last
FROM Friend AS F
LEFT JOIN Parent AS P ON F.ParentID = P.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set foreign key to ParentID(must be primarykey in table parent).
2. Use JOIN as

   select Parent.FirstName,Parent.LastName from Parent JOIN Friend on Parent.ParentID=Friend.ParentID;

Comment: What about friends that don't have parents.

Comment: Not mentioned here.

Comment: Sure it is... the user says they are selecting from the friends table and instead of the id they want to see the names.  This would limit the results and just be **wrong**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should always be looking at when you structure a database is trying to make sure every column has a use, and no columns are duplicates (foreign keys obviously don't count). What purpose does having an `ID` column and a `Parent ID` column in the `Parent` table serve? You might want to consider getting rid of one of those columns. (I say this because I am currently optimizing a database with useless/duplicate information all over the place and I can only advise you and anyone else who reads this early that learning how to 'normalize' a database is a a huge advantage that will help you save literally countless hours down the line.)

To answer your question specifically, this query should work (at least for t-sql)

```
Select f.id, f.firstname, f.lastname, p.parentid, p.firstname, p.lastname
From Friend f
Left Join Parent p on p.parentid = f.parentid
```

You can edit the column names according to how they are in the DB, since you put spaces in I'm assuming that's not how they're stored.

Comment: What about friends that don't have a valid value in the parentid column?

Comment: If it's set up correctly to be a foreign key then that should be impossible, if not every friend has a parent then this gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Not at all complicated... just use a left join.  Like in my answer.  And it would be possible... the key could be null.  I don't think calling that setup as "correct" there is an expectation you won't have all data here.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the possibility. Generally a table that has foreign keys don't allow them to be null, which is why I didn't think about it first. Good catch!

Comment: actually in my experience generally they do.  I work with a 3 T db every day and every single f key in our db could be null and we never "set them up correctly" to fail in that case.   Of course I've only been working with SQL for 25 years -- so maybe I missed those?

Comment: Well you definitely trump me in terms of SQL experience... I've been working on SQL for close to two years now and haven't come across a null FK yet.... Thanks for that info!

Comment: Or you have lots of bugs you haven't found yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple join statement. An example is

`SELECT Friend.ID, Friend.FirstName, Friend.LastName, Parent.LastName, Parent.FirstName
FROM Friend
JOIN Parent ON Parent.ID = Friend.ParentID`

Comment: What about friends that don't have a valid parent id?

Comment: once the parent_id is a foreign key, each friend's parent_id should be valid

Comment: This is not actually the way real world databases work.  See my comments on Aaron's answer.

Comment: oh, i haven't come across a foreign key with null value before.  thanks, i'll be on the look out from now on

Answer (score 0):

The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.
Syntax

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

SELECT a.FirstName,a.LastName
FROM Parent a JOIN Friends b ON a.ParentID=b.ParentID;